# Increment a counter in VXML

Tags: xml, counter, vxml, voicexml

I'm sorry that this is probably a really basic question but I'm just beginning to program. Basically I need to increment a counter in VXML.

I've declared the counter as:

```
  <var name="i" expr="0" />
```

and in an IF statement I've incremented by doing this: the second assign tag increments the counter.

```
<if cond="the_aveland_high_school"> <prompt> Thank you I have recognised a school</prompt> <assign name="arrEmpty[i]" expr="'the_aveland_high_school'"/> <assign name="i" expr="++"/> </if>
```

Is that concept correct?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @vtd-xml-author - yes vxml is VoiceXML

Answer (score 6):

I think information was left from your question.  I believe you asked if:

```
<var name="counter" expr="0"/>
...
<if ...>
    <assign name="counter" expr="counter+1"/>
```

Yes, that is one way to increment a counter.  You can also perform your logic directly in ECMAScript within a  element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<vxml version="2.1" application="tellmeu_root.vxml">
  <var name="iStudentID" />
  <var name="iStudentPIN" />
  <var name="iRetries" expr="1" />

  <catch event="event.retry_login">
    <prompt>Invalid i d or password</prompt>
    <assign name="iRetries" expr="iRetries+1" />
    <if cond="iRetries == giMaxLoginRetries">
      <throw event="event.login_retries_exceeded" />
    </if>
    <goto next="#get_id" />
  </catch>
```